# What regions of the US will have *improved* climate given current predictions of climate change?

Tags: climate-change, models, human-influence, predictability, global-weirding

This is really a two part question:

1) Is there a good model for mapping climate conditions in a particular location to pleasantness or livability or something like that?

2) If there is such a model, has anyone applied this livability index to predictions of future climate changes?  An perhaps created a map?

Ideally it would easy to answer questions of the form: would Detroit or San Francisco likely have a more pleasant climate in 2050?

Comment: In general, climate change will cause more extreme weather events (ice storms, heat waves, etc). So even if the average temperature rises from 17 to 18 (or whatever) and it seems to be a nicer on an average day, the extreme weather events will make it miserable. Also see this answer by David Hammen that's a bit relevant: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/13203/725

Answer (score 3):

Answering my old question:

I've found two sources that attempt to answer the GDP change brought about by predicted future climate change.  The short answer is that places north of about Chicago should see an increase in GDP and places south of Chicago should see a decrease in GDP.

[image: Climate Change and GDP change in the USA]

[image: Climate Change and GDP change Worldwide]

https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/06/29/534896130/mapping-the-potential-economic-effects-of-climate-change

[https://web.stanford.edu/~mburke/climate/map.php](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emburke/climate/map.php)